# ActiveAdmin: sort by child association's property

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I am having these objects:

```
class District < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
end
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :districts
end
```

What I would like to do (and been unable to do so thus far), is: have a `City` column in `District`'s index and that column should be sortable on `City.name`.

Closest thing I was able to do without crashing ActiveAdmin is:

```
index do
  column City.human_name(:count => :other), :city, :sortable => :city_id
end
```

Which of course is not good enough; I don't want to sort on foreign key's integer value.

Tried stuff like `:sortable => 'city.name'`, gives an error. Even tried to do it like you do it on "pure" Rails - `:joins => :cities, :sortable => 'city.name'` - no luck. Tried a bunch of other stupid stuff, got annoyed and decided to humbly ask for help.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: what did your solution end up being..

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That should also do the work:

```
index do
  column City.model_name.human, :city, :sortable => 'cities.name'
end

controller do
  def scoped_collection
    end_of_association_chain.includes(:city)
  end
end
```

Comment: any ideas on how to sort by the count of the association? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924458/activeadmin-sort-by-association-count

Comment: @alexBrand, I'd also use the counter cache approach, as suggested in the replies to your question. Cheers.

Comment: shorter version, just add line "includes :city" instead of all "controller do" stuff

Answer (score 10):

Try this.. It will help....

```
index do
  column :city, :sortable => :"cities.name" do |district|
    district.city.human_name(:count => :other) if district.city.present?
  end
end

controller do
  def scoped_collection
    District.includes(:city)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Very simple and readable solution:

```
index do
  column :city, sortable: "cities.name"
end

controller do
  def scoped_collection
    # join cities
    super.includes :city
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the name of the table, probably `cities`. It might look like this:

```
District.joins(:city).order("cities.name")
```

Comment: I know this. I meant ActiveAdmin's DSL, though. Happily, it got fixed like 14 hours ago -- https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/pull/623