# Sort a table_for in rails activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

In an active admin show page, I've got two panels, the first being the primary record, the second being associated info (by has_many) so `show` looks like this:

```
panel "Max Amount" do
  table_for user.max_amount do
    column 'Amount', :amount
    column 'time', :updated_at
  end
end
```

Can i sort this high-to-low (or low-to-high) on the amount column?

Update: I found the source for the demo ( https://github.com/gregbell/demo.activeadmin.info/blob/master/app/admin/users.rb ) which seems to have sorting but when you go to the actual demo site it's not working. Is this feature perhaps broken? Is there a work-around?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The only way I found to do it was a bit hacky.  ActiveAdmin will pass in the column name and asc/desc via the params hash, then you can add that to your query.

Also, make sure to pass "sortable: true" into the table_for call.

```
panel "P&L" do
  table_for Quote.order(params[:order].gsub('_', ' ')), sortable: true do
    column("Revenue", sortable: :revenue) { |quote| number_to_currency quote.revenue }
    column("Profit", sortable: :profit)  { |quote| number_to_currency quote.profit  }
  end
end
```

Comment: Great solution, sadly the `sortable: true` option didn't take affect for me on a show pages of an active admin resouce. Although I do see it in the source code and it should work.

Comment: oh nvm, it works great. I just forgot the `sortable: :column_name` in my case.

Answer (score 8):

With rails 4.2, based on @idrinkpabst, I did the following:

```
table_for group.devices.order(
  # Support for column name with underscore
  # Support "no sort param"
  (params[:order] ? params[:order] : '').gsub('_asc', ' asc').gsub('_desc', ' desc')
), sortable: true do
  # Directly using symboles and not using sortable:
  column :presence
  column :serial_number
  column :apk_version
  column :firmware_version
end
```

It's a more robust version:

- allows column name with underscore
- support "no sort param"
- works with rails 4.2

Answer (score 4):

ActiveAdmin now supports table sorting.

```
table_for ride.bookings.order('updated_at desc') do
  column :name
  column :created_at
end
```

This, thanks to Ryan Bates's screencast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin?view=asciicast

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the accepted [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16431800/7573223)

I would recommend a more "universal" solution:

The problem comes from column_names with underscore `_` character or needing to sort on nested attribute values as pointed out in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7781193/7573223). The order argument needs to have the associated table name, which may contain an underscore `_` character as well. This solution fails when that happens.

However, a minor change solves for this case and can be used in either case:

```rb
Quote.order(params[:order].gsub('_', ' ')
```

becomes, as suggested and explained by this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59597812/7573223)

```rb
Quote.order(params[:order].sub(/.*\K_/, " ")
```

```rb
panel "P&L" do
  table_for Quote.order(params[:order].sub(/.*\K_/, " ")), sortable: true do
    column("Revenue", sortable: :revenue) { |quote| number_to_currency quote.revenue }
    column("Profit", sortable: :profit)  { |quote| number_to_currency quote.profit  }
  end
end
```

If you wish to avoid regexps then I recommend looking at other solutions to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3185144/7573223) that fits your needs.