# ActiveAdmin: sort by association count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have the following models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :reviews
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

I would like to sort the users on my ActiveDdmin page by the number of reviews that each user 
has.

I tried this, but no luck: (from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781193/activeadmin-sort-by-child-associations-property))

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  filter :name
  index do
    column :name
    column :email
    column "Facebook" do |u|
      if u.provider == "facebook"
        "Yes"
      end
    end
    column "No. of reviews", :sortable => :"reviews.count" do |u|
      u.reviews.count
    end

  end

  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      end_of_association_chain.includes(:reviews)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest to use a [counter_cache](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column) on your user model for your reviews and then simply use this column in ActiveAdmin directly:

```
index do
  # ...
  column "No. of reviews", :sortable => :reviews_count
end
```